# copy and paste in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following services in docker-compose.yml

```
wildfly:
    build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.wildfly
        context: .
    volumes_from:
        - logvolume
    depends_on:
        - logvolume
        - mariadb-wildfly

mariadb-wildfly:
    extends:
        file: common-services.yml
        service: mariadb-common
    # ports:
    #     - "3307:3307"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

firefly:
    build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.wildfly
        context: .
    volumes_from:
        - logvolume
    depends_on:
        - logvolume
        - mariadb-firefly

mariadb-firefly:
    extends:
        file: common-services.yml
        service: mariadb-common
```

There will be a lot more of these similar services. Each one consist of wildfly and a correspondig maria-db. Unfortunatly I cannot use something like :

```
wildfly-moskito:
    extends:
        file: common-services.yml
        service: wildfly-common
```

Because extend is not allowed for services that use volumes_from or depends_on. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this "copy and paste" - Issue more elegant.

Comment: How about a docker-compose.override.yml https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case?

Comment: How'd you go with this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @yamenk, a docker-compose would fit the bill.
Especially if you just want different service names based off the same image.

If you want something more complicated/dynamic though you could use a tool like Jinja modified to generate compose templates.

- https://github.com/webcrofting/meta-compose

I can't find any examples unfortunately.